# How to hit cache?

Tags: c++, caching, compilation, cpu

I am using tdm64/ mingw32.
Lets say I have a class with constructor:

```
class test{
  int number;
  int dependent;
  test( int set_number){
    number = set_number;
    dependent = some_function(number);
  }
}
```

Will code be faster if I would switch to:

```
dependent = some_function(set_number);
```

And if I need some explanation. Basicly does first option have to wait with function call until number will be sent back to RAM? Or does it have to wait because queue of instructions is partially empty waiting for not calculated yet variable? Is number pulled back for operation from cache? L1? L2? L3?  Will it have to wait multiple CPIs or just one? Which assembly instructions will be generated out of those two following lines?

```
number = set_number;
dependent = some_function(number);
```

What sort of assembly instruction will be generated to assign number and than to handle number sending for some operation in function?
What if I will have multiple situations like this mixed with array operations in the middle of them?

Comment: You can answer this yourself by: (A) getting your compiler to output assembly for the two approaches; and/or (B) writing a benchmark to actually test it.

Comment: How can I make Code-Blocks (gcc/tdm64) to output assembly?

Comment: `gcc -S` will produce assembly. For small, self-contained snippets you are better off just using [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org)